# Unexpected behavior in assigning 2d numpy array to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4, 1)), columns=['A'])
y = np.random.randn(4, 2)
x['A'] = y
```

I expect it to throw an exception because of shape mismatch. But pandas silently accepted the assignment: `y`'s first column is assigned to `x`.

Is this an intentional design? If yes, what is the rationale behind?

I tried both `pandas` 0.21 and 0.23.

---

Thanks for those who tried to help. However, nobody gives a satisfactory answer although the bounty is going to expire.

Let me emphasis what is expected as an answer:

1. **whether this design is intentional? Is it a bug ? Is it a false design?**
2. **what is the rationale to design it in this way?**

---

Since the bounty is going to expiry, I accepted the most voted answer. But it does not provide a answer to the above questions.

Comment: Seems to be a peculiarity with `'A'` already being a column. For isntance x['B'] = y gives you the expected `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

Comment: I would expect this to raise key error instead...

Comment: oh yeah, there is one too.

Comment: I agree that the situation is still unclear. In light of this, I don’t think that there should be an accepted answer. I opened an [issue about this on the `pandas` repository](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40827), and it seems like it may be a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values in `y` are un-indexed matrix. The case `x['A'] = y` works here as it take the first item from the matrix and assign it to the `'A'`.

Similarly,

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4, 2)), columns=['A', 'B'])
y = np.random.randn(4, 2)
x[['A', 'B']] = y
```

will also work because the extra data is being discarded by pandas.
If you're trying to pass less columns, say:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4, 2)), columns=['A', 'B'])
y = np.random.randn(4, 1)
x[['A', 'B']] = y
```

That will also work as it will assign the same values to both the columns. This case is similar to `x['A'] = 0` which will replace all the data in column `A` with zeros.

Comment: what do you mean by "un-indexed matrix" and what is the first item of `y`? the first columns?

Comment: @LiuSha Dataframe and Series have index. as `np.random.randn` is a list of list its un-indexed.

Answer (score -1):

for

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4, 1)), columns=['A'])
y = np.random.randn(4, 2)
```

if x['A'] = y ;then column is replicated and if we iterate it with different column lengths such as:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4, 3)), columns=['A','B','C'])
y = np.random.randn(4, 2)
```

and try x['A'] = y then also first column is replicated but if we equate x = y then the x data frame is replicated with y matrix. 
So i guess we are getting this ambiguity as we are trying to equate a data frame column with a matix created in numpy.
Hope it explains

Answer (score -1):

Pandas series are numpy array, since its one columns, it treats it as one object, to which the reference has changed.

```
>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.zeros((4,1))
>>> x = np.random.randn(4,2)
>>> y= np.zeros((4,1))
>>> y
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])
>>> x
array([[-1.00731291, -0.37151425],
       [-0.78154847, -0.72854126],
       [-0.98566253,  1.68786232],
       [ 0.12614892,  0.41804799]])
>>> y = x
>>>y
array([[-1.00731291, -0.37151425],
       [-0.78154847, -0.72854126],
       [-0.98566253,  1.68786232],
       [ 0.12614892,  0.41804799]])
```